# docker container didn't send any data

Tags: docker, rust, containers, yew, trunk-rs

running `docker build -t <IMAGE_NAME> .` then running `docker run -p 8080:8080 <IMAGE_NAME>` logs to console that it works but 127.0.0.1:8080 does not display the client

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/72412733/169354228-2ab6bc5b-4cdd-4026-afe4-5c41f8c50717.png]

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/72412733/169354294-f0140f59-dbe7-4327-bceb-afcf75681f9a.png]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.60.0-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN rustup target add wasm32-unknown-unknown
RUN cargo install --locked --version 0.15.0 trunk
RUN trunk build --release

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["trunk", "serve", "--release"]
```

Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "yew-whos-that-pokemon-client"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
getrandom = { version = "0.2.4", features = ["js"] }
rand = "0.8.5"
reqwest = "0.11.10"
serde_json = "1.0.81"
wasm-bindgen-futures = "0.4.30"
web-sys = "0.3.57"
yew = "0.19.3"
```

this works perfectly fine locally and i tried with multiple browsers

reference to source code if needed to solve this issue: https://github.com/apinanyogaratnam/yew-whos-that-pokemon-client

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Comment: does your project work with `cargo run --release` too ? and not just in debug.... if it does, it a docker problem

Comment: It's a bit different since trunk behaves differently so in my case, `trunk serve` is the option rather than using cargo to run my application. Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`server listening at http://127.0.0.1:8080` means that the server will only accept connections from 127.0.0.1, i.e. localhost.

In a container, localhost is the container itself, so your program won't accept connections from outside the container.

To get it to do that, you should have your program bind to `0.0.0.0` which will cause it to accept connections from anywhere.

I'm not a Rust expert, but it seems there's an `--address` option on `trunk serve` you can use to tell it what address to bind to. I haven't been able to find an example. Only these [release notes](https://github.com/thedodd/trunk/releases/tag/v0.15.0) where they say they've changed the default bind address from `0.0.0.0` to `127.0.0.1` for security reasons and introduced the `--address` option in case you need to set another address.

Update: I tried downloading your project and if I change the CMD statement in the Dockerfile to

```
CMD ["trunk", "serve", "--release", "--address", "0.0.0.0"]
```

it works.